# Directory in MVC3 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a "Tools" area of the MVC3 site I'm currently working on. One of the tools I'm integrating on the site I need to run in a virtual directory. Setting up a virtual directory under the /Tools folder works fine for the app itself, but for navigation to /Tools/, I'm getting "Directory listing not allowed". How do I tell IIS to let MVC routes handle this URL?

We'll be using IIS6 in production, so it's important for it to work with that.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: For clarity, here's the setup:

- /Tools/RoutedTool1
- /Tools/ToolInVirtualDirectory
- /Tools/RoutedTool2
- /Tools/

The routes for the routed tools work fine, but since I had to create a directory under the root to setup the "ToolInVirtualDirectory", IIS is hijacking the "/Tools/" request and trying to send it to the directory, ignoring the route.

Comment: Are you just creating a virtual directory, or are you making it an application as well?

Comment: Just creating a virtual directory so far, but if there's a technical reason to switch it to an app I'm all ears. As far as I can tell, the problem is independent of the virtual directory- adding just the Tools directory messes up my routes.

Comment: That's weird, it should be the other way around.  The route should override a virtual directory.  Do you have any url rewrite rules in place?

Comment: Nope. Is there an IIS setting dictating what gets hit first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true` in Global.asax.cs.

Remember that since this property plays at global level you have to ignore the css files and other stuff you don't need to handle by the routing infrstructure before setting this. For more idea please refer this [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/authorizing_folders_using_routeexistingfiles).

Answer (score 0):

In your RegisterRoutes section in Global.asax, you add ignore routes that the routing system ignores.  There should already be an example for .axd's in the config.

Comment: I added some clarification to the question- ignoring routes doesn't seem to be my issue. Thanks.